# Table formula to give most recent entry edit

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-forms

[Here is an image of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXNGD.png), with inputs coming from a Microsoft Form. We have a unique `ID` for each entry, and fields `x`, `y`, `z`, which are mandatory in the form.

We can also "edit" those fields via the form, but since Microsoft Forms doesn't have an edit feature (which looks up entries in the table and then appends the appropriate cells), it's treated as another entry and is just another row in the table. When editing a field, I want the user to only be required to enter data for the field they are editing.

For each field, I want the latest, non-empty field of the corresponding ID to be displayed under the red headers (`actual x`, `actual y` and `actual z`), on the row where the ID was registered. Refer to IDs `a` and `b` in the table, and the desired output.

At the moment, if we wanted to edit field `x` for ID `c`, then we'd populate the new value of `x`, and the old `y` and `z` values - you can see this in the table. Then if we wanted to edit field `y` for ID `c`, we'd also have to populate the latest values of `x` and `z`. The formula I use to get the end result (for column `actual x`), is

`=IF(ISNA(XLOOKUP([@[ID register]],[ID edit],[field x edit])), [@[field x register]], XLOOKUP([@[ID register]],[ID edit],[field x edit],,,-1))`

but it would fail for IDs `a` and `b`. How would I resolve this?

Greatly appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: If I'm not wrong then I can say that U want  to pull the LAST entry of each ID under both category Y & Z ,,,, like A 870 and 250 for B 1900 and for C 6000 & 600 , if yes pleas confirm so that I'll try to fix it !

Comment: The last Non-empty entry - so yes, for A we want 7, 870 and 250 for x, y and z. As x has not been edited for A, we want to display the original value it was registered with.